# How to read international letters correctly from filenames in web2py / python application

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, web2py

I have a web2py (python 2.x version) small application that reads filenames from a directory and put the filenames in a list:

```
import os
#path where to scan for files
path  =request.folder + "uploads"
#change cwd to pathfilenames - needed in web2py
cwd = os.chdir(path)

filenames = list(file for file in os.listdir(path))

return filenames
```

If the filename contains only english letters everything is normal.
If the filename contains international letters like for instance

> αγθψ

etc the these letters are converted to

> ����.

The problem is that the filename is lost and further parsing is not an option.
I have searched and experimented extensively with many examples of the unicode() , encode and decode  methods but without luck. For instance, if I use unicode() to represent a greek filename like this

```
filenames[1] = unicode(filenames[1])
return filenames[1]
```

I get the error

> type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'> 'ascii' codec can't decode
>   byte 0xf6 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Same situation when using:

```
filenames[1] = (filenames[1]).encode('ascii', 'ignore') or 'utf8'
```

I have read the [python 2 unicode howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) but found nothing to help in my case.
I have no idea on how to proceed.
In python 3 there is no such problem and the filenames are correctly presented. Web2py uses python 2.x
 Any help or point to a direction would be appreciated. Thank you

## #################    EDIT ##########################

Further experiments and if the light of this [Unicode Frustrations](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html) , web2py gave again the following errors for the code below:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
        filenames.append (str(file))
        return filenames[1]
```

and the error was

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position
>   5: ordinal not in range(128)

By using

```
filenames.append (str(file))
```

I have a string but with the same problems again.

> Newfd����OpenDocument.odp

I have used as well

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

at the beginning of the web2py controller file but with no luck as well.

Comment: Where does the error occur? web2py internally expects UTF8-encoded byte strings (which in Python 2.x is an `str` object), so if `filename` is an UTF-8 encoded unicode object, you'll want `filename.encode("utf-8")`. If it's not UTF-8, you'll need to decode (`filename.decode(...)`) from that encoding and encode to UTF8.

Comment: @cdonts Many thanks for the suggestion which I will keep in mind. I have some progress by using os.listdir(u'.'). I will notify is case I find something. Many thanks for your effort. –

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more information.